# Why should we have SonarQube end analysis step after build step in TFS?

Tags: sonarqube, tfsbuild

Why should we have SonarQube end analysis step after build step in TFS ?
Shouldn't we end analysis before build and stop building in case of quality gate failed ?

Answer (score 0):

The way analysis is structured with the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild is that analysis "eavesdrops" on the build. So essentially, the begin step tells it to start listening. The end step tells it to stop listening, consolidate the analysis report & send it off to the server.

Comment: Could you please  be more eloborative? I m having difficulty understanding this..

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but I try to answer anyway.

The process of analyzing a project using Scanner for MSBuild goes something like this:

1. The begin step sets up a hook to run the analyzers, to be triggered by a build.
2. When you build the project with MSBuild, this triggers the analyzers, through the hook that was set up in the begin step.
3. The end step collects the results produced by the analyzers during the build, and sends to SonarQube. SonarQube checks the quality gate and updates its status. The end step also cleans up the hook, to prevent affecting other, unrelated builds.

What you're asking is not possible by design:

> Shouldn't we end analysis before build and stop building in case of quality gate failed ?

Since the analysis is triggered during build, it happens at the same time as the build, it's not possible to "end analysis before build", as it hasn't even started yet. Even worse, the quality gate status will be only known after the analysis result is pushed to SonarQube, which happens during the end step, which needs to come after the build.